# Arc between points in circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, plotly

I'm trying to plot a Chord diagram using Matplotlib. I am aware that already existing libraries, such as Plotly give me that functionality but I would really like to do it in matplotlib.

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.axhline(0, color='black', linestyle='--')
ax.axvline(0, color='black', linestyle='--')

npoints = 3

# Calculate the xy coords for each point on the circle
s = 2 * np.pi / npoints
verts = np.zeros((npoints, 2))
for i in np.arange(npoints):
    angle = s * i
    x = npoints * np.cos(angle)
    y = npoints * np.sin(angle)
    verts[i] = [x, y]


# Plot the arcs
numbers = [i for i in xrange(npoints)]
for i, j in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=2):

    if i == j:
        continue

    x1y1 = x1, y1 = verts[i]
    x2y2 = x2, y2 = verts[j]

    # Calculate the centre of the Arc
    mxmy = mx, my = [(x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2]

    r = np.sqrt((x1 - mx)**2 + (y1 - my)**2)
    xy = [mx - r, my - r]
    width = 2 * r
    height = 2 * r
    start_angle = np.arctan2(y1 - my, x1 - mx) * 180 / np.pi
    end_angle = np.arctan2(y2 - my, x2 - mx) * 180 / np.pi

    arc = patches.Arc(mxmy, width, height, start_angle, end_angle)
    ax.add_patch(arc)

# Plot the points
x, y = verts.T
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=50, c='r')
ax.annotate("1", (x[0], y[0]), xytext=(x[0] + .5, y[0] + .5))
ax.annotate("2", (x[1], y[1]), xytext=(x[1] - 1, y[1] + .5))
ax.annotate("3", (x[2], y[2]), xytext=(x[2] - 1, y[2] - 1))

ax.set_xlim(-npoints - 5, npoints + 6)
ax.set_ylim(-npoints - 5, npoints + 6)
ax.set(aspect=1)
```

Is anyone able to tell me why my plot looks like this?
[image: my plot]

I'm expecting something more like the following (image taken from [Plotly](https://plot.ly/python/chord-diagram/))

[image: chard plotly]

---

#### Edit 1

I would like to draw arcs between the following points:

- 1 and 2
- 1 and 3
- 2 and 3

These arcs should ideally be on the inside.

---

#### Edit 2

After some further investigation I figured that the `end_angle` seems to be the root of the problem.

Comment: Do you mean `plotly` rather that `pyplot` because `pyplot` *is* `matplotlib`

Comment: I guess your main problem is the calculation of the center of the arcs. The center can not just be the mean of the coordinates of the two points....

Comment: read the ref: `...we draw a cubic Bézier curve ...` a bit more math that prevents the curves intersecting at points with high multiplicity that makes visually tracing them difficult.    Perhaps manipulating Arc w, h params could give similar effect

Comment: That isn't quite a runnable example -- `length` isn't defined and you use a hardcoded 20 where you want a `numpoints`. Fix those and work with `npoints=3`, which will let you see what your code is actually doing as you change it.

Comment: You have a math problem, not a coding problem. Personally, I would go through the arc-making code using paper and pencil (literally drawing the geometry) looking for my thinko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @f5r5e5d pointing out the `Bézier curve` used in plotly, I've decided to give this one a go. It looks like this is the way to go in my case, too.

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

npoints = 5

# Calculate the xy coords for each point on the circle
s = 2 * np.pi / npoints
verts = np.zeros((npoints, 2))
for i in np.arange(npoints):
    angle = s * i
    x = npoints * np.cos(angle)
    y = npoints * np.sin(angle)
    verts[i] = [x, y]

# Plot the Bezier curves
numbers = [i for i in xrange(npoints)]
bezier_path = np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01)
for a, b in itertools.product(numbers, repeat=2):
    if a == b:
        continue

    x1y1 = x1, y1 = verts[a]
    x2y2 = x2, y2 = verts[b]

    xbyb = xb, yb = [0, 0]

    # Compute and store the Bezier curve points
    x = (1 - bezier_path)** 2 * x1 + 2 * (1 - bezier_path) * bezier_path * xb + bezier_path** 2 * x2
    y = (1 - bezier_path)** 2 * y1 + 2 * (1 - bezier_path) * bezier_path * yb + bezier_path** 2 * y2

    ax.plot(x, y, 'k-')

x, y = verts.T
ax.scatter(x, y, marker='o', s=50, c='r')

ax.set_xlim(-npoints - 5, npoints + 6)
ax.set_ylim(-npoints - 5, npoints + 6)
ax.set(aspect=1)
```

The code above plots what I wanted it do to. Some modifications on the style and it should be good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the underlying problem was "how can I draw a chord diagram in matplotlib", I just want to let you know that there is now a python library to do that: [mpl-chord-diagram](https://github.com/Silmathoron/mpl_chord_diagram).

You can just do `pip install mpl-chord-diagram`.

[disclaimer] I am the current maintainer [/disclaimer]